# Keep getting an Error using ggplot & R session aborted

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling

Hi I am  very new to this so I appreciate your patience  , having a bit of trouble running this code.

Issue:
When ever I use any formation of ggplot I receive an error. Session Aborts and I have to start over from beginning.

What I have tried:
I have tired updating, reinstalling,checking my R version, reinstalling packages,try using a different code chunk with different data, running the code chunk in bite size ect.
I have  a linux system
R Version 1.4.1106
not using the server version or cloud R

Error :

> Error elf_dynamic_array_reade

I have attached a photo because I can't copy the error message. R simply restarts.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)


data(penguins)
View(penguins)

ggplot(data=penguins)+
  geom_point(mapping
             = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g))
```

[image]

Comment: You mention your RStudio version, but what version of R are you using? you can check by entering `R.version.string` in the Console.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest RStudio version.

Comment: @MrFlick Its is "R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)"

Comment: R.version.string is for R, the link you provided is for RStudio. Those are separate things. I know that RStuido needed to be updated for R 4.1, but I thought you just needed at least 1.4.+ but I guess there were still some things that were fixed in even more recent versions. Glad it's working.

Comment: @MrFlick I downloaded the latest version from here https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ and that seem to have got it working but still received a warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point). I notice when I run R.version.string to double check for update I got the following "R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)"     But when I check for update via the Help menu it no longer says need update and recommend a download but states "You're using the newest version of RStudio"

Comment: @MrFlick Oh Thanks for helping me understand that and assisting me with getting it back up and running. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: That warning message is fine. There are two penguins with missing measurements. You can't draw points for missing values so it just lets you know what's going on.